# In IIS6.0 after installing ASP.NET 4.0 the Edit Configuration button is disabled

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6

Have several IIS6.0 servers running .NET 4.0.  On some of them, when right clicking on a specific website and hitting the ASP.NET tab, the Edit Configuration and Global Configuration buttons are disabled.

Tried running aspnet_regiis with -r and -iru switches and didn't seem to help.

Any suggestions please?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide more details about the sites for which the button is disabled?  For example, are the sites set up as applications or virtual directories?

Answer (score 0):

please download and update .NET4.0 SP1, http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39257
hope this usefull.